# Web3 not being detected - google chrome extension

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, react

I am working on a google chrome extension that operates when a user opens up a new tab. Upon opening a new tab, my dapp should connect to the user's web3 provider. However, no web3 is being detected.

Everything works fine if deployed as a simple webpage.

I am just running into said issue when I try to operate my dapp as a chrome extension, with it beginning to run when opening a new tab.

Here is `truffle-react`'s setup which I did not edit for retrieving web3:

```
let getWeb3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
// Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 
injection timing.
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var results
var web3 = window.web3

// Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)

  results = {
    web3: web3
  }

  console.log('Injected web3 detected.');

  resolve(results)
} else {
  // Fallback to localhost if no web3 injection. We've configured this to
  // use the development console's port by default.
  var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545')

  web3 = new Web3(provider)

  results = {
    web3: web3
  }

  console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');

  resolve(results)
}
})
})
```

Comment: Is your local node running with rpc port 9545 and web3 api exposed?

Comment: yes i have my rpc set up for port 9545. However, I thought this didn't matter considering i was running it through infura

Comment: But in logic given here, when web3 object is not found , you fallback to localhost, there is no link to infura api here?

Comment: I replaced the localhost link with my infura link. I removed the smart contract call, and now there are no errors. However, I am still running into a `No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.` console log

Comment: i have tried to answer this question step by step. after replacing localhost link with, infura link it will work, just console output is ambiguous.

Comment: Where is your code running? MetaMask only injects `web3` into `http://` and `https://` pages. If this code is running in either a background script or a content script, then MetaMask will not inject `web` into the `window` that your script can see (since these scripts are running in a `chrome-extension://` context). `web3` will only be visible from scripts injected into the page.

Answer (score 1):

This code checks for check for instance already available in window

```
var web3 = window.web3
```

If found, check for Mist/Metamask or any other provider, and return web3,
and console outputs to **'Injected web3 detected.'**

```
// Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)

  results = {
    web3: web3
  }

  console.log('Injected web3 detected.');
```

else if web3 instance is not found, this code fallback to localhost node
web3 provider, so console outputs to **'No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.'**

```
// Fallback to localhost if no web3 injection. We've configured this to
  // use the development console's port by default.
  var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545')

  web3 = new Web3(provider)

  results = {
    web3: web3
  }

  console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
```

As in your case you are **not running local ethereum node**, it is throwing error.

But as suggested by me, you have replaced localhost link with infura link.

**Now there is no error.Why? because web3 has been injected.**

But still console output is same, it's because console command still is same.

```
 console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
```

To check whether web3 has been instantiated & injected, just check web3 version

```
console.log(web3.version.api) // for web3 0.2x.x
```

or

```
console.log(web3.version) // for web3 1.0
```